# LINQ to SQL - Dynamic Table Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am currently working on a payment provider. I want to get the transaction table name from the Provider configuration for use in my LINQ queries but understand that the following example is not possible:

```
[Table(Name = Config.TransactionTable)]
public class Transaction : ITransaction
{
   ....
}
```

I get the following error at compile time when I do the above:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

What would be the best approach to this problem and is using LINQ to SQL to acheive what I want out of the question?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute (`TableAttribute`) is `sealed`, which limits many options; however, LINQ-to-SQL is not tied to the attribute model - there are other providers. Most notably, you might look at using the xml model provider, and generating the xml at runtime. This is the `MappingSource` parameter in the overloaded constructor; a typical usage would be `XmlMappingSource.FromXml(...)` or similar.

However, it generally seems pretty uncommon that the core tables will change at runtime. Uncommon, but not unsupported.

For reference, the implicit default is `AttributeMappingSource`.

Comment: The table structure will remain the same it is just the ability to allow the user to specify their own table name that I need to provide more flexibility in my provider. I will look further into your suggested option - thanks.